# Show that $G \times H$ is divisible if and only if $G$ and $H$ are both divisible

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ and $H$ be abelian groups, written additively. Show that $G \times H$ is divisible if and only if $G$ and $H$ are both divisible.

**My attempt:** Suppose that $G$ and $H$ are both divisible. If $(a_1,a_2) \in G\times H$, then $(a_1,a_2)= (nb_1,nb_2)=n(b_1,b_2)$. Thus $G\times H$ is divisible. Conversely...? I try this, Assume that $G\times H$ is divisile and consider $(a_1,a_2)\in G\times H$, then $(a_1,a_2)=n(b_1,b_2)=(nb_1,nb_2)$, that is, $a_1=nb_1 \in G $ and $a_2=nb_2 \in H $. Thus, the groups $G$ and $H$ are both divisible. Am I right?

Comment: It is ok! Good job.

Comment: I would quibble and say that to show $G$ is divisible, you should start with an element of $G$ and not with an element of $G\times H$. So, let $a_1\in G$, $n\gt 0$. We need to find $a_2\in G$ such that $na_2=a_1$. Then you should find an element of $G\times H$ that helps you find $a_2$. You do not seem to do that, though your argument can be made part of such an argument.

Comment: Likewise, you should explain how you know that $(b_1,b_2)$ exists in the first part; you should *explicitly* use that $G$ and $H$ are divisible, and you do not do so. If I were grading this, I would give you only partial credit in both directions.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You're right, Mr. Arturo. I really appreciate every comment you make. Thank you, I will see how I can improve what I have done.